# Moving elements to the end of a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, cjk

I want to solve two problems regarding sorting my list in python.

1) In my list, there is an element starts with `"noname"` and a number comes after it like this, `"noname3"` or `"noname4"` (each list contains only one `noname`+`number`)

This `noname` aggregates all the `nonames` and the number after it shows however many `nonames` are there.

My question is that how can I send this `noname`+`integer` element to the end?

2) As you can see below, `sorted` function will sort English first then Korean. Is there any way that I can sort Korean first then English? Of course `'noname'` at the end.

```
names =  ['Z', 'C', 'A B', 'noname3', 'ㄴ', 'ㄱ', 'D A', 'A A' , 'ㄷ']
sorted(names)

# Output
['A A', 'A B', 'C', 'D A','noname3', 'Z', 'ㄱ', 'ㄴ', 'ㄷ']

# Desired Output
[ 'ㄱ', 'ㄴ', 'ㄷ', 'A A', 'A B', 'C', 'D A', 'Z', 'noname3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `key` function that sorts the `noname` items higher than the non-`noname` items.

```
sorted(names, key=lambda x: (x.startswith("noname"), x))
```

Comment: it works perfectly fine, do you have any idea about the order of english and korean by any chance?

Comment: hint: you can use `ord`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how exactly Korean characters are alphabetized, here's my attempt (based on @kindall's start). Note, you can pass a custom function into the `key` parameter of the sorter

```
def sorter(char):
    #Place english characters after Korean
    if ord(char[0])>122:
        return ord(char[0])-12000
    else:
        return ord(char[0])+12000

lst=['Z', 'C', 'A B', 'noname3', 'ㄴ', 'ㄱ', 'D A', 'A A' , 'ㄷ']

sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x.startswith('noname'),sorter(x)))

['ㄱ', 'ㄴ', 'ㄷ', 'A B', 'A A', 'C', 'D A', 'Z', 'noname3']
```